# Should be an element "cleaned" before setting innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen several times in a project that I'm working that before setting an element's innerHtml the value  is cleaned before, like this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo')
foo.innerHTML = '';
foo.innerHTML = '<span>Bar</span>'
```

I can't find any good reason to do this, just that everyone in the team follows this "practice". From what I understand, anyone can redefine the innerHtml property to do a customized action, but besides this reason, is there any other one that I'm missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: Example code updated to avoid skewing (thanks @freefaller )

Comment: Thanks @freefaller, the example is much clearer with this (not to mention an implementation =P )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like the project's seen some [cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) at some point.

Not only is there absolutely no reason to set an element's .innerHTML property *twice*, but it's actually slowing down the page needlessly. Every modification made to the DOM causes the browser to stop and update the document tree, meaning cycles are being wasted every time .innerHTML's being set to an empty string.

Comment: Definitely this cargo-cult thing happened (never knew there was a term for this). I was almost sure of no good reasons to do these kind of things, now I'm 100% sure. Thanks! ;)